# Pokemon go iOS lost account

Tags: pokemon-go

Hi I was playing Pokemon go with my daughter we lost connection and was trying to reload the screen, my daughter clicked on log into another account by accident, I logged in using my account details and it has started a new game. 
Does anyone know how to retrieve my old account, signed in with gmail but it just puts me on this new game.
Thanks 
Matt

Answer (score 0):

- Click on the middle button, that resembles a Pokéball
- In the top right corner click on the cogwheel *("Settings")*
- Scroll down and click on *Sign Out*

This will throw you back to the login screen. Pick the correct account and you'll have your data back.

Sign in with your old account - most likely a trainer account, unless your phone has multiple google accounts attached (in that case try all accounts until you find the correct one).

Comment: Already tried that sadly it won't load it up always the new account

Comment: Did you click on `Trainer Account`?